# How to use SELECT LEFT('echo $rows['cardnumber']', 5)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I want to post the users' cardnumber in the formular. It has to be posted after the cardnumber is typed in and saved. All this works, but i don't want that all of the characters are shown - only the last four characters.

I have tried this:

`<input name="cardnumber" size="20" maxlength="16" type="text" id="cardnumber" value="<?php echo SELECT LEFT('$rows['cardnumber']', 4) ?>" />`

- but it won't work..

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You are seriously confusing PHP and SQL here, it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have already executed the query and stored it int the `$rows` variable.

Try;

```
<?php echo substr($rows['cardnumber'], -4); ?>
```

Comment: Dom: Thanks a lot!! Just what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value="<?php echo substr($rows['cardnumber'],0, 4) ?>"
```